# How to add text before website link, fx store.mywebsite.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, web

Now to be clear I don't want javascript to just change the url once my page is loaded.
I want to be able to type something like 'blog.mywebsite.com' into the omnibar and actually have it find my website like steam with 'store.steampowered.com/'.
How would you do this?
Would you place files in a specific directory, tweak the .htaccess file, or is there some file you can tell how to handle link that have prepended text.

I might be missing something completely obvious and this might be very simple, but any response would be appreciated.

Comment: so far what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to add a folder next to main 'www' folder in my ftp client.
Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a subdomain and the most typical way of doing it is through your hosting provider, log in to cpanel or whatever dashboard your hosting provider provided you with and you should see something that says subdomain.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for 10/10

Answer (score 0):

if you need to redirect every one who access a.com to b.com on apache you can use the .htaccess file like this:

```
    Redirect 301 / http://b.com/
```